# How can I ensure a hung Thread eventually gets garbage collected in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got a long running program which periodically makes connections to external network resources.  I've wrapped those calls in a timeout thread, so if the call takes more than 10 seconds, the call returns an error immediately, like so:

```
def fetch_resource(url):
    class TimeoutThread(Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.result = None

        def run(self):
            self.result = requests.get(url)

    tt = TimeoutThread()
    tt.start()
    tt.join(10.0)
    if tt.result:
        return tt.result.content
    else:
        return None
```

Reading the Thread documentation, however, it appears `Thread.join()` will return either:

1. When the thread terminates, or
2. In 10 seconds

In the case where `.join()` returns in 10 seconds, the thread is still alive, correct?  I understand there are no good ways to kill the thread, but how do I ensure the thread eventually terminates and gets garbage collected?  I'm worried that threads might hang and never return, thus gradually eating up resources which never get freed.

Comment: If you have a long running thread, you probably have that running inside some loop right? Add a check inside that loop that if self.__quit, for example, is set to True, you exit the loop. You can overwrite the thread'd join method to set self.__quit to True, ending the loop and thread execution.

Comment: The potentially long running thread is `self.result = requests.get(url)`.  So no, it's not in a loop.

Comment: Then I suppose it would depend on the logic inside of requests.get(url) to return eventually. What is it doing?

Comment: Making a network call to a url

Comment: Cant the network call time out then? Otherwise, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know why you’re bothering with a separate thread, given that your main thread is blocked while waiting for the request to complete or timeout, anyway. Why not simply have the request timeout?

Note that you can call [Socket.setdefaulttimeout](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout) to impose a default timeout on Socket objects created from that point on, e.g. in libraries which do not themselves give you an option for specifying a request timeout.